# Change items in drop down box in Wordpress Website

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I am new to Wordpress, and I am attempting to build a website using it. I am trying to create a contact us page. What I am trying to do is almost exactly what Amazon's Contact Us  page does.

I am going to display some buttons, and when the user clicks the button, I want data that is in a dropdown box to change so the user can click on an item in the dropdown box. I have no clue how to achieve this in WordPress. I have searched, but I don't think I am wording my searches correctly, and I am not sure if regular websites would work the same. I can't even figure out how to make my own PHP or Javascript's in WordPress, I am looking more into that now.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) to build a contact page.